# Images for tabs on TabPanel not fully loading on IE8 in EXT JS3

Tags: tabpanel, extjs3

Ext JS 3.2.2

In IE8, the tabs on my tab panel are not fully populating their images. It looks like the top and right sides. Any ideas on what causes this and how to fix?

See attached screenshot.

[image: Tabs in IE8]

Comment: you can change the CSS like .x-tab-top{border:solid}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the zoom setting is > 100%, I got this issue. Once I reduced to <= 100%, it went away.